# Compiling error on gradle custom plugin using external plugin (groovy files)

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

We are trying to create a custom plugin. In this plugin we pretend to use gradleFx plugin internally to extends some classes.

When we try to build the plugin, it fails because gradlefx classes cannot be found:

we tried to define dependencies in different ways, from the build.gradle when we apply groovy plugin, and also we tried from groovy classes like this:

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
   void apply(Project project) {
      project.dependencies {
         compile 'org.gradlefx:gradlefx:1.3.3'
      }
   }
}
```

Anyway none of this works when we try to extends a gradleFx class:

```
import org.gradlefx.tasks.adt.AdtTask

MyTask implements AdtTask {
}
```

because AdtTask doesn't exists, the error we see is ***unable to resolve class org.gradlefx.tasks.adt.AdtTask***

How's the right way to declare dependencies and extend from them in my groovy files?

Comment: Where does the plugin code live? Is it a project for the plugin alone? Can you show your project layout?

Comment: it's a stand-alone plugin, with this structure:

    src/main/groovy/com/company/MyPlugin.groovy
    src/main/groovy/com/company/MyTask.groovy
    build.gradle (here we import groovy plugin to use gradleApi() and build the final jar)